# Same key problem when creating json data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to convert HTML elements to a JSON object with JSON stringfy.

But it does not convert elements with the same data attribute.

I want use `data[]` to define object arrays.

How I can do this?

If you run the code snippet, you will see that there's no page 1.

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function() {
    var li = {};
    $(this).children('li').each(function() {
      
      switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
        case "page":
          li.page = {
            id: $(this).data("menu-id")
          };
          break;
        case "external-link":
          li["external-link"] = {
            title: $(this).text().trim(),
            url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
            icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
          }
          break;
        case "dropdown":
          li.dropdown = {};
          li.dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
          }).text().trim();
          li.dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function() {
            var data = {};
            $(this).children("li").each(function() {
              switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
                case "page":
                  data.page = {
                    id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                  };
                  break;
                case "external-link":
                  data["external-link"] = {
                    title: $(this).text().trim(),
                    url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                    icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                  }
                  break;
              }
            });
            return data;
          }).get();
          break;
      };



    });
    return li;
  }).get();

  var obj = {
    menu: allmenus
  };
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
  $('#menuinput').val(jsondata);
  console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ol class="dragger_1 dragger-menu vertical">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="1">Ana Sayfa<span class="text-danger float-right menu-rem"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us<span class="text-danger float-right menu-rem"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger_2 dragger-menu vertical">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
</ol>
```

I would like a JSON data output as below;

```
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "page": {
            "id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "page": {
            "id": "25"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "page": {
            "id": "28"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason page 1 is not added is because it gets replaced by subsequent pages. You need to add the `data` as array for the individual menus.

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function () {
   var li = {
      data: []
   };

   $(this).children('li').each(function () {
      var item = {};

      switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
         case "page":
            item.page = {
               id: $(this).data("menu-id")
            };
            break;
         case "external-link":
            item["external-link"] = {
               title: $(this).text().trim(),
               url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
               icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
            }
            break;
         case "dropdown":
            item.dropdown = {};
            item.dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function () {
               return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
            }).text().trim();
            item.dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function () {
               var data = {};
               $(this).children("li").each(function () {
                  switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
                     case "page":
                        data.page = {
                           id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                        };
                        break;
                     case "external-link":
                        data["external-link"] = {
                           title: $(this).text().trim(),
                           url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                           icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                        }
                        break;
                  }
               });
               return data;
            }).get();
            break;
      };

      li.data.push(item);
   });
   return li;
}).get();

var obj = {
   menu: allmenus
};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
$('#menuinput').val(jsondata);
console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<ol class="dragger_1 dragger-menu vertical">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="1">Ana Sayfa<span class="text-danger float-right menu-rem"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us<span class="text-danger float-right menu-rem"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></li>
</ol>

<ol class="dragger_2 dragger-menu vertical">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
</ol>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```